# Efficiently eliminate common sub-expressions in .NET Expression Tree

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, optimization, expression-trees

I've written a DSL and a compiler that generates a .NET expression tree from it. 
All expressions within the tree are side-effect-free and the expression is guaranteed to be a "non-statement" expression (no locals, loops, blocks etc.).  (**Edit**: The tree may include literals,  property accesses, standard operators and function calls - which may be doing fancy things like memoization inside, but are externally side-effect free).

Now I would like to perform the "Common sub-expression elimination" optimization on it.

For example, given a tree corresponding to the C# lambda:

```
foo =>      (foo.Bar * 5 + foo.Baz * 2 > 7) 
         || (foo.Bar * 5 + foo.Baz * 2 < 3)  
         || (foo.Bar * 5 + 3 == foo.Xyz)
```

...I would like to generate the tree-equivalent of (ignore the fact that some of the short-circuiting semantics are being ignored):

```
foo =>
{
     var local1 = foo.Bar * 5;

     // Notice that this local depends on the first one.        
     var local2 = local1 + foo.Baz * 2; 

     // Notice that no unnecessary locals have been generated.
     return local2 > 7 || local2 < 3 || (local1 + 3 == foo.Xyz);
}
```

I'm familiar with writing expression-visitors, but the algorithm for this optimization isn't immediately obvious to me - I could of course find "duplicates" within a tree, but there's obviously some trick to analyzing the dependencies within and between sub-trees to eliminate sub-expressions efficiently and correctly.

I looked for algorithms on Google but they seem quite complicated  to implement quickly. Also, they seem very "general" and don't necessarily take the simplicity of the trees I have into account.

Comment: What do you mean by dependencies between subtrees? Didn't you say these are side-effect-free?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, there are no side-effects. By "dependency" I simply meant that `foo.Bar * 5 + foo.Baz * 2` has a dependency on `foo.Bar` amongst others (i.e. `foo.Bar` exists in its sub-tree).

Comment: Do you consider `(a + b) + c` equivalent to `a + (b + c)`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, it's not necessary for the algo to optimize on the basis of 'special' properties of operations like associativity (or commutativity etc.)

Comment: Can you post example of what you want to achieve by specifying Before & After optimization trees. Removing Local is not easy as dynamic composing of expression is different then compiled expressions. Also optimization may not be very helpful as SQL will optimize query before executing it.

Comment: @AkashKava: I did post a before/after example, except I did it with C# lambdas rather than with tree-diagrams. Also, this has nothing to do with Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities.

Comment: You asked me to comment on this question; I am not an expert on this optimization so I don't have much to say other than: make sure you clearly understand what resource you are optimizing for. CSE decreases time by eliminating redundant computations but increases space usage. Increased space usage can translate into contention on registers, more cache misses, etc, which might make things worse. This is a tricky optimization and I would only do it if I had strong evidence that the time win was large compared to the space cost.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Many thanks. My example is quite simple, but in my real scenario, the sub-expressions involved may not be cheap to compute and are likely to contain some duplication. Consequently, I'm relatively confident that performing this optimization will be a net perf win.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're correct in noting this is not a trivial problem.

The classical way that compilers handle it is a [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) representation](http://books.google.com/books?id=Pq7pHwG1_OkC&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=compiler%20dag%20representation&source=bl&ots=4Xb2Luc3qU&sig=5sEUKcDmo7CiRHx5fqG3mfovwcM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dfzGUp3yIonQsATfmoHIDQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=compiler%20dag%20representation&f=false) of the expression.  The DAG is built in the same manner as the abstract syntax tree (and can be built by traversing the AST - perhaps a job for the expression visitor; I don't know much of C# libraries), except that a dictionary of previously emitted subgraphs is maintained. Before generating any given node type with given children, the dictionary is consulted to see if one already exists.  Only if this check fails is a new one created, then added to the dictionary.

Since now a node may descend from multiple parents, the result is a DAG.

Then the DAG is traversed depth first to generate code.  Since common sub-expressions are now represented by a single node, the value is only computed once and stored in a temp for other expressions emitted later in the code generation to use.  If the original code contains assignments, this phase gets complicated.  Since your trees are side-effect free, the DAG ought to be the most straightforward way to solve your problem.

As I recall, the coverage of DAGs in the [Dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design) is particularly nice.

As others have noted, if your trees will ultimately be compiled by an existing compiler, it's kind of futile to redo what's already there.

**Addition**

I had some Java code laying around from a student project (I teach) so hacked up a little example of how this works.  It's too long to post, but see [the Gist here](https://gist.github.com/gene-ressler/8278298).

Running it on your input prints the DAG below. The numbers in parens are (unique id, DAG parent count).  The parent count is needed to decide when to compute the local temp variables and when to just use the expression for a node.

```
Binary OR (27,1)
  lhs:
    Binary OR (19,1)
      lhs:
        Binary GREATER (9,1)
          lhs:
            Binary ADD (7,2)
              lhs:
                Binary MULTIPLY (3,2)
                  lhs:
                    Id 'Bar' (1,1)
                  rhs:
                    Number 5 (2,1)
              rhs:
                Binary MULTIPLY (6,1)
                  lhs:
                    Id 'Baz' (4,1)
                  rhs:
                    Number 2 (5,1)
          rhs:
            Number 7 (8,1)
      rhs:
        Binary LESS (18,1)
          lhs:
            ref to Binary ADD (7,2)
          rhs:
            Number 3 (17,2)
  rhs:
    Binary EQUALS (26,1)
      lhs:
        Binary ADD (24,1)
          lhs:
            ref to Binary MULTIPLY (3,2)
          rhs:
            ref to Number 3 (17,2)
      rhs:
        Id 'Xyz' (25,1)
```

Then it generates this code:

```
t3 = (Bar) * (5);
t7 = (t3) + ((Baz) * (2));
return (((t7) > (7)) || ((t7) < (3))) || (((t3) + (3)) == (Xyz));
```

You can see that the temp var numbers correspond to DAG nodes.  You could make the code generator more complex to get rid of the unnecessary parentheses, but I'll leave that for others.

Answer (score 15):

You are doing unnecessary work, common sub-expression elimination is the job of the jitter optimizer.  Let's take your example and look at the generated code.  I wrote it like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var lambda = new Func<Foo, bool>(foo => 
               (foo.Bar * 5 + foo.Baz * 2 > 7)
            || (foo.Bar * 5 + foo.Baz * 2 < 3) 
            || (foo.Bar * 5 + 3 == foo.Xyz));
        var obj = new Foo() { Bar = 1, Baz = 2, Xyz = 3 };
        var result = lambda(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; internal set; }
    public int Baz { get; internal set; }
    public int Xyz { get; internal set; }
}
```

The x86 jitter generated this machine code for the lambda expression:

```
006526B8  push        ebp                          ; prologue
006526B9  mov         ebp,esp  
006526BB  push        esi  
006526BC  mov         esi,dword ptr [ecx+4]        ; esi = foo.Bar
006526BF  lea         esi,[esi+esi*4]              ; esi = 5 * foo.Bar
006526C2  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+8]        ; edx = foo.Baz
006526C5  add         edx,edx                      ; edx = 2 * foo.Baz
006526C7  lea         eax,[esi+edx]                ; eax = 5 * foo.Bar + 2 * foo.Baz
006526CA  cmp         eax,7                        ; > 7 test
006526CD  jg          006526E7                     ; > 7 then return true
006526CF  add         edx,esi                      ; HERE!!
006526D1  cmp         edx,3                        ; < 3 test
006526D4  jl          006526E7                     ; < 3 then return true
006526D6  add         esi,3                        ; HERE!!
006526D9  mov         eax,esi  
006526DB  cmp         eax,dword ptr [ecx+0Ch]      ; == foo.Xyz test
006526DE  sete        al                           ; convert to bool
006526E1  movzx       eax,al  
006526E4  pop         esi                          ; epilogue
006526E5  pop         ebp  
006526E6  ret 
006526E7  mov         eax,1  
006526EC  pop         esi  
006526ED  pop         ebp  
006526EE  ret
```

I marked the places in the code where the `foo.Bar * 5` sub-expression was eliminated with HERE.  Notable is how it did not eliminate the `foo.Bar * 5 + foo.Baz * 2` sub-expression, the addition was performed again at address 006526CF.  There is a good reason for that, the x86 jitter doesn't have enough registers available to store the intermediary result.  If you look at the machine code generated by the x64 jitter then you *do* see it eliminated, the r9 register stores it.

This ought to give enough reasons to reconsider your intend.  You are doing work that doesn't need to be done.  And not only that, you are liable to generate *worse* code than the jitter will generate since you don't have the luxury to estimate the CPU register budget.

Don't do this.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I assume all of these were simple field-backed properties? This is not the case in my problem - the properties may well be computed. In fact, there will also be side-effect-free method calls. I can't rely on the JITter for this.

Comment: Clearly you are also overlooking the inlining optimization, the jitter can *tell* that a method doesn't have side-effects.  Proving it in your own code would be only useful for cases where the jitter can't tell.  Which requires you to tackle delegates and virtual methods, good luck with that.

Comment: But Hans, I *know* that everything in the tree is side-effect free. It's really hard for the Jitter to figure it - there may be calls to many pure functions. There may even be memoization going on.

Comment: Common sub-expression elimination *is* memoization of course.  I fail to see how you can prove that methods are free of side-effects when you can't even prove it for the simple expressions you asked about.  Clearly I'm unconvinced but cannot help if you just wave your hands with assertions that are this vague.

Comment: @HansPassant How do you check what machine code will be generated for given C# code? I know you can check MSIL using tools like ILSpy. How do you move further into machine code?

Comment: Use Debug + Windows + Disassembly.  Only look at the Release build, use Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick "Suppress JIT optimization".

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a `SortedDictionary<Expression, object>` that can compare arbitrary `Expression`s.
   (You can define your own arbitrary comparison function here -- for example, you can lexicographically compare the *types* of the expressions, and if they compare equal then you can compare the children one by one.)
2. Go through all the leaves and add them to the dictionary; if they already exist, then they're duplicates, so merge them.
   (This is also a good time to emit code -- such as creating a new variable -- for this leaf if it's the first instance of it; you can then store the emitted code inside the `object` value in the dictionary.)
3. Then go through the parents of all the previous leaves and add them to the dictionary; if they already exist, then they're duplicates, so merge them.
4. Keep on going up level by level until you reach the root.

Now you know what all the duplicates are, and where they occur, and you've generated code for all of them.

Comment: This looks ok. Is it theoretically correct, i.e. does it work in all situations? Also, this would generate unnecessary locals, so I would have to do another pass to "re-inline" locals that are used only once. Also, can you explain why the dictionary needs to be sorted? I could just use a standard unsorted one, yes? For equality, I can just use http://stackoverflow.com/a/673246/412770

Comment: @Ani: Yes equality works fine too, you can just use the one you linked to. I personally like sorting because I like making guarantees, and sorting guarantees O(log n) lookups, whereas hashing is just based on luck. Regarding unnecessary locals, yes it does, so you'll have to re-inline locals afterward. However I think you can avoid it if you delay the generation of locals until you've verified the existence of a duplicate -- i.e., keep a counter, and only create the locals if the counter becomes >= 2. If you go left-to-right, I think this should keep the order of the dependencies correct.

Comment: The traversal order here is important. If I understand the algo correctly, any order which traverses all nodes while guaranteeing that a child is visited before a parent is good enough, yes? I didn't understand the left-to-right bit and why that's relevant.

Comment: @Ani: I think so. I think the left-to-right bit might only be relevant if you have multiple statements (which you don't), in which case you want to make sure the variable is declared before you use it. You can probably ignore it here.

Comment: And regarding the "re-inlining", it's quite inefficient to do. Consider the duplicate-free `(foo.Bar + 3) * 6`. We would generate `var l1 = foo.Bar; var l2 = 3, var l3 = l1 + l2; var l4 = 6; var l5 = l3 * l4; return l5;` It's going to take multiple inlining passes to get rid of everything. Surely we can design an integrated algorithm that doesn't require this?

Comment: @Ani: You can keep pointers from every variable back to where it was used, to ensure it's linear-time.

Comment: @Ani: Sorry, I think you can't avoid the re-inlining using the procedure I mentioned earlier in my comment. There is probably another way though, I'm not sure. You can almost certainly keep it single-pass linear time though, if you keep backpointers to every usage site.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I have never tackled a problem like this, I'm just throwing out an idea that seems reasonably efficient:

For every node in the tree have some sort of signature.  A hash should do, collisions can be dealt with.  The signature must map all Foo.Bar entries to the same value.

Traverse the tree (O(n)) building a list of signatures of INTERNAL nodes (ignore leaves), sort on a combined key of expression size and then signature (O(n log n)).  Take the most common item of the smallest expression in the list (O(n)) and go through replacing the expression with a local variable.  (Check that they are truly matches at this time just in case we had a hash collision.  B)

Repeat this until you accomplish nothing.  This can't possibly run more than n/2 times, thus bounding the whole operation to O(n^2 log n).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with hans-passant about the practicality of doing this. However, if you're researching this academically you may be interested in the Quine-McCluskey algorithm. Beware this is a very complex problem. Mathematica has a very nice all-purpose expression optimizer and depending on your needs you may be able to just use it - e.g. [if you feed it your expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A%20*%205%20%2b%20B%20*%202%20%3E%207%29%20OR%20%28A%20*%205%20%2b%20B%20*%202%20%3C%203%29%20OR%20%28A%20*%205%20%2b%203%20=%20X%29):

[image]

(foo.Bar = A, foo.Baz = B, foo.Xyz = X)