# Fastest way to memoize expression

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees, memoization

I have a function, that transform input `Expression` to output `BlockExpression`. So I write this code:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<Expression, BlockExpression> MemberMemoizeDictionary = new Dictionary<Expression, BlockExpression>(); 
    private static BlockExpression CreateBody<TProperty>(CustomComparer<T> comparer, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> member, bool createLabel)
        where TProperty : IComparable<TProperty>, IComparable
    {
        BlockExpression expression;
        if (MemberMemoizeDictionary.TryGetValue(member, out expression))
        {
            return expression;
        }

        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) (member.Body is MemberExpression ? member.Body : ((UnaryExpression)member.Body).Operand);
        BlockExpression result = comparer.CreateCompareTo<TProperty>(memberExpression, createLabel);
        MemberMemoizeDictionary[member] = result;
        return result;
    }
```

but it's not working.

I was thinking that `Expressions` are immutable, so I can use them as dictionary keys, but I see it's not true.

What is easiest and fastest way to solve this problem? It's always a single member-expression, with a possible `convert` due to boxing of value-type properties.

Comment: "its not working" care to expand on that? What is it or isn't it doing?

Comment: Dictionary keys need to not be mutated while they're in the dictionary, but that alone isn't enough.  They also need to have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations that have the desired semantics.

Comment: Why do you want to memoize this? This doesn't look like an expensive method.

Comment: @svick because entire complexity is hidden in `CreateCompareTo` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xantos stated, the expression trees are reference equal, so you cannot use them as dicrionary key. Use the MemberInfo as your key, that will work.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<MemberInfo, BlockExpression> MemberMemoizeDictionary = new Dictionary<MemberInfo, BlockExpression>(); 
private static BlockExpression CreateBody<TProperty>(CustomComparer<T> comparer, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> member, bool createLabel)
    where TProperty : IComparable<TProperty>, IComparable
{
    BlockExpression expression;
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) (member.Body is MemberExpression ? member.Body : ((UnaryExpression)member.Body).Operand);
    if (MemberMemoizeDictionary.TryGetValue(memberExpression.Member, out expression))
    {
        return expression;
    }

    BlockExpression result = comparer.CreateCompareTo<TProperty>(memberExpression, createLabel);
    MemberMemoizeDictionary[member] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Disclaimer: I didnt check if this code compiles, but i think you get the point :)

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking that Expressions are immutable

True

But note that expressions are regenerated every time!

```
public static Expression Exp = null;

public static void Foo(Expression<Func<bool>> exp)
{
    if (Exp == null)
    {
        Exp = exp;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(Exp, exp));
    }

}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Foo(() => true);
}
```

writes

```
False
```

Sadly "literal" `Expression`s aren't "interned" by the C# compiler. It is even written somewhere in the MSDN.

Comment: Of course, the problem isn't even just that equal expressions aren't always reference equal, but rather that the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations of `Expression` also use reference semantics, not value semantics, and writing a valute-based comparer would be...hard.

Comment: @Servy Your sentence implies that there are `Expression.Equals` and `Expression.GetHashCode` overloads that are "badly done"... But there aren't! :-) It is more similar to collection types that don't have comparers :-)

Comment: I *stated* that they have reference semantics.  I made no value judgement at all about whether or not that was a good decision, but rather that the OP seems to be under the impression that they behave differently than they actually do.

Comment: @Servy *Equals and GetHashCode implementations of Expression* There is a (light) implication that there is a specific (non-default-`object`) `Equals` implementation/overload in the `Expression` class. Clearly your sentence could be interpreted as "the class `Expression` subclasses the `object` class and takes as its own all the `object` methods", but it was open to interpretation. I was quipping on that. And I **do** feel that a `Expression.Intern` would be a good idea.

Comment: Whether there is a custom implementation or merely the use of the inherited implementation is *irrelevant*.  What matters is how the implementation behaves, not who wrote it.  The behavior of those methods is that the identity of the object is the object's reference.  How that came to be is purely trivia.

Comment: While this clearly explains the problem, it doesn't actually offer any solution.

Comment: @svick You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/673205/613130 There are some solutions there...