# How to add Expression of Func Of T, Bool to List only in Add scope?

Tags: c#

I have list `new List<Expression<Func<Test, bool>>>`

and I'd want to add item to with all operations in `.Add()` scope

How can I achieve that?

```
var a = new List<Func<Test, bool>>();

var b = new List<Expression<Func<Test, bool>>>();

a.Add
(
    new Func<Test, bool>(x => x.test == false) // works
);

b.Add
(
    new Expression<Func<Test, bool>>(x => x.test == false) // fails
);
```

Comment: Look at this
[Maybe you find your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673205/how-to-check-if-two-expressionfunct-bool-are-the-same)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because you can't declare an expression that way -> that constructor does not exist. Simply passing ` x => x.test == false` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the type and let the compiler infer it:

```
var a = new List<Func<Test, bool>>();

var b = new List<Expression<Func<Test, bool>>>();

a.Add
(
    x => x.test == false
);

b.Add
(
    x => x.test == false 
);
```